# Alinhar texto a cima do botão

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Olá, gostaria de alinhar um texto que tenho sempre acima do botão dentro de um card bootstrap, para que sempre fique formatado da maneira correta, independente do tamanho do meu texto que está dentro do card, pois de acordo com o tamanho do texto, o nome do jornalista fica em posições diferentes, queria ter um padrão para ficar melhor visualmente

Segue a imagem para entenderem oque estou falando, estou com esse problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem saberia como resolver ? so preciso que sempre fiquem na mesma "linha"

```
<div class = "container">

<div class = "row">
        <div class="card-deck mt-1">
      <div class="card">
            <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotolgbt.jpeg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotolgbt2.png" alt="Terceiro Slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Por João Das Flores</small></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block embaixo ">Leia mais</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocurso1.jpg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocurso2.png" alt="Terceiro Slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Por João Das Flores</small></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block embaixo ">Leia mais</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocdb1.jpeg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocdb2.jpeg" alt="Terceiro Slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Por João das Flores</small></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block embaixo ">Leia mais</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta.

Comment: acabei de colocar,obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque o `<p>` (nome do autor) e o `<a>` (botão "Leia mais") dentro de uma div e coloque a classe `.mt-auto`, e aplique as propriedades `display: flex;` e `flex-direction: column;` na classe `.card-body`. Isso fará com que o nome do autor e o botão fiquem sempre alinhados no final do card:

```css
.card-body{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class = "container">

<div class = "row">
        <div class="card-deck mt-1">
      <div class="card">
            <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotolgbt.jpeg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotolgbt2.png" alt="Terceiro Slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          <div class="mt-auto">
             <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Por João Das Flores</small></p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block embaixo ">Leia mais</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocurso1.jpg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocurso2.png" alt="Terceiro Slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          <div class="mt-auto">
             <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Por João Das Flores</small></p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block embaixo ">Leia mais</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocdb1.jpeg" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="primeiralinhafotos/fotocdb2.jpeg" alt="Terceiro Slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          <div class="mt-auto">
             <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Por João das Flores</small></p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block embaixo ">Leia mais</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: resolveu, muito obrigado.